# Want to convert a array in json format with specific format?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array in the format

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [Name] => Anaa Airport (AAA)
        [IsDomestic] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Name] => Arrabury Airport (AAB)
        [IsDomestic] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to change it to this format

```
[
{"Name":"Anaa (AAA)","Id":1,"IsDomestic":0},
{"Name":"Arrabury (AAB)","Id":2,"IsDomestic":0},
]
```

I have tried json_encode function but this is giving me something like this

```
{"1":{"Id":1,"Name":"Anaa Airport (AAA)","IsDomestic":0},
 "2":{"Id":2,"Name":"Arrabury Airport (AAB)","IsDomestic":0}
}
```

I don't want that 1,2 keys which.

I want to get the data in the exact form mentioned.

Comment: But why you want to change the format?

Comment: some developer wants that format from me.

Comment: Hi itried this but i got this format `"[{"Id":"1","Name":"Anaa Airport (AAA)","IsDomestic":"0"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Arrabury Airport (AAB)","IsDomestic":"0"}]"`

array structure is 

`array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "Id" => "1"
    "Name" => "Anaa Airport (AAA)"
    "IsDomestic" => "0"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "Id" => "2"
    "Name" => "Arrabury Airport (AAB)"
    "IsDomestic" => "0"
  ]
]`

Comment: are you working on api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` to rearrange the array in the desired order, than use `array_values` in `json_encode` for the output

```
$r = array_map(function($v){
  return [
      'Name' => str_replace('Airport ','',$v['Name']), 
      'Id' => $v['Id'], 
      'IsDomestic' => $v['IsDomestic']
  ];
}, $a1);//$a1 is the input array
echo json_encode(array_values($r));
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/GZr6Q

Comment: no need of array_map just put `$a` array in `echo json_encode(array_values($a));`.it will give you what you want.You can check it in your working example.

Comment: @CodeBreaker read the question carefully, see the input array and the result.Name and ID index order has been changed.

Comment: No need for the map. While arrays in PHP are in fact an ordered map, a JSON object is unordered. http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt

Comment: @ankr in the input `array` the order of keys are `Id, Name, IsDomestic`, but in the result mentioned order are `Name, Id, IsDomestic `  which is `[
{"Name":"Anaa (AAA)","Id":1,"IsDomestic":0},
{"Name":"Arrabury (AAB)","Id":2,"IsDomestic":0},
]`, I am not sure why the downvotes , why you guys are not reading the question and mentioned input/output carefully

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it fits every need in the question.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz thank you..!! at least some one have eyes who can read clearly..:)

Comment: @RakeshJakhar It doesn't matter. Properties on a JSON object are _not_ ordered.

Comment: @ankr see what OP mentioned in his last line `I want to get the data in the exact form mentioned.` ?

Comment: That part is correct, but that was not your original argument.

Answer (score -1):

Use [array_values()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to remove index

```
$json_out = json_encode(array_values($your_array_here));
```

Comment: are you sure that this will give you the desired output as OP mentioned , which is `[
{"Name":"Anaa (AAA)","Id":1,"IsDomestic":0},
{"Name":"Arrabury (AAB)","Id":2,"IsDomestic":0},
] ?`

Comment: yes! i checked it.in your given working example.See buddy you are being strict towards the order of the OP mention, but it does not matter either name will come first or id will.

Comment: @CodeBreaker OP don't need `Airport` word in the `Name` where you have removed that ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$your_array = Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [Name] => Anaa Airport (AAA)
        [IsDomestic] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Name] => Arrabury Airport (AAB)
        [IsDomestic] => 0
    )
);

$new_array = [];
foreach($your_array as $array)
{
  $new_array[] = json_encode($array);
}

dd($new_array);
```